# Need a hover to slide left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a hover header for my site, but having a lot of trouble getting it to do what I want. I have individual smaller divs to display staff members and when hovered over I want it to give a slide effect, preferably to the left.

Ok, I created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/2badzt19/

HTML:

```
<div class="staffinfo">
<a class="first-link" href="">
<img src=http://i57.tinypic.com/23tsj0i.jpg>
</a>
<a href="">
Admin Info
</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.staffinfo a{
color: white;
text-decoration:none;
text-align: center;
display:block;/* important */
}

.staffinfo, .first-link{
-webkit-transition: 0.3s;
-moz-transition: 0.3s;
-ms-transition: 0.3s;
-o-transition: 0.3s;
transition: 0.3s;     
}


.staffinfo{
height: 100px;
font: normal normal 700 1em/4em Arial,sans-serif;
overflow: hidden;
width: 120px;
background-color: #3b5998;
}

.staffinfo:hover{
background-color: #003D99;
}

.staffinfo a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
}

.first-link{
margin-top: 0em;   
}


.staffinfo:hover .first-link{
margin-top: -7em;
}
```

How would I make it slide left? And how can I display it as a table of 6 images the same size, 2 columns, 3 rows?

Comment: You need to do a `text-align:right` on the object you want to expand to the left. Then do a `width` change on hover on it. %)p

Comment: answer me YES or NO!  
you want to slide <div class="stafftext1"> instead of just displaying  when mouse hover ?

Comment: That's correct. I want the staffpic1 to be seen, and stafftext1 to slide left on hover

Comment: Why do you have `<style>` tag inside a table? and where are you closing this table? and the best part of this Q is that the code is totally unreadable -_-

Comment: I'm very sorry, I'd add the entire header code but I'm having trouble getting it to display properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres how I'd do it, no table but a list:

HTML

```
<ul class="slider">
    <li><a href="">Admin Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="">User Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Something Else</a></li>
    <li><a href="">What?</a></li>
    <li><a href="">More</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.slider
{
    width:280px;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}

ul.slider>li {

    height: 100px;
    font: normal normal 700 1em/4em Arial, sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #3b5998;
    background-image:url("http://i57.tinypic.com/23tsj0i.jpg");
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

ul.slider>li>a {
    display:block;
    margin-left:120px;
    width: 120px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;
}

ul.slider>li:hover>a {
    margin-left:0px;
    background-color: #003D99;
}
```

Basically, the `a` is offset to the right via a margin the same with of the `li`. This margin is removed on hover of the `li`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h1z66neu/)

[Now with sexy transparent background](http://jsfiddle.net/h1z66neu/1/)

[Or if you want inline images](http://jsfiddle.net/h1z66neu/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was after!

Comment: Sorry, one last thing. How would I have it so there's a different pic for each item? I have 6 spaces to cover.